# PageHandler In php

Tags: php

I am currently working in a application like wordpress. i need a php class to handle the url request for eg : if u load the below url in browser

http://somename.com/myaboutpage/

the handler should load the file `about-us.php` from my theme folder

and if i use the below url

http://somename.com/action/login/

the handler should trigger the file `login-action.php` from my application core and return the values

how its possible..

i tried to study how elgg & wordpress handle the request. but i am unable to get the exact..
so please help me.

**Note**  the pages i create will be dynamic so i need a page handler fully dynimic like word press permalink handler

Comment: Normally to change the URLs you would either change the httpd.conf file for Apache or edit the .htaccess file.  (or both).

Comment: @JohnHalsey i have done it using htaccess but i how can handle the url requested by users

Comment: "**application like wordpress**" but don't manage to create a route-handler...

Comment: @Xatenev can i know why `but don't manage to create a route-handler.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set a BASE_URL in an index.php file?  if you have, you could check to see if that is set, if it isn't it means the user has somehow managed to navigate directly to your about-us.php file.  So something like

```
if(!defined('BASE_URL'))
{
   require('/*your index.php file*/');
   header('Location: BASE_URL')
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Or have totally misunderstood?  In your theme, do you have module files that just calls the content for that particular page into index.php, or do you have a separate file for each page?

Comment: separate page for each page

Comment: I'm not sure in that case.  I would have thought you need something in a config file with a switch block that checks the page loaded and sets the url to something specific.  From what I've learnt about WordPress, you wouldn't create a separate file for each page, you would just have a module file that holds the main content for that page, then calls header files and footers files etc.

Comment: i am trying to create like a wordpress theme engine

Comment: This is a good blog I read a while ago about creating wordpress themes.  http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-build-a-custom-wordpress-theme-from-scratch

Comment: i am trying to create a new theme engine like wordpress theme engine